# In a 'has_many', how to order field first by not null, then by value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

For example if you have:

```
has_many :certs, -> { order cert_date: :desc }, :dependent => destroy
```

I want null cert_dates to be the first entries returned, and then have cert_dates return in descending order.

Equivalent to sql query :

```
select * from certs order by cert_date is not null, cert_date desc;
```

Answer (score 2):

Exactly as you wrote in sql:

`has_many :certs, -> { order('cert_date is not null, cert_date desc') }`

If you use postgres it can be done a bit cleaner (not sure about MySQL though):

`has_many :certs, -> { order('cert_date desc nulls first') }`